# Can a list passed to a function be modofied by another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Integer getElement( List<Integer> list ) {

   int i = Random.getInt( list.size() );

   return list.get( i );

}
```

The question: while this function has been called from a thread, IS there a way the list passed to this function can be modified by another thread?

Comment: I don't know why people are upvoting this question.  For a start, "thread safe" and "can be modified by another thread" do NOT mean the same thing.

Comment: @StephenC: Agreed. "thread safe" is "can be modified by another thread" *SAFELY*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `java.util.List` doesn't guarantee thread safety. The list can be changed between `list.size()` and `list.get()` by another thread. Moreover memory inconsistency is also a problem.

I could think three ways to solve it:

1. Use immutable list. Collections.unmodifiableList(list) is fine, Guava's [ImmuntableList](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) is better.
2. [Synchronized](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) the list. but you have to synchronize the list instance all over the program.
3. List in [java.util.concurrent](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html&rct=j&q=java%20concurrent%20package&ei=SMd9Tu_9Fs2aiQeS2Lm0Dg&usg=AFQjCNEWXhttp://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). It's a sophisticated concurrency solution.

Comment: This will also not work because another thread can modify it without synchronizing on it.

Comment: @Hemal: you are correct. I removed my wrong code in my answer.

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>(list)` can cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception, just as `list.get( i )` can.

Comment: No, just these two times I was correct. Overall, I have been incorrect lot more then I have been correct. See my answer for what I think are the only options when using **mutable** lists.

Comment: More information in the answer on what you mean by "memory inconsistency" would improve the answer; right now it's ill-defined. The memory is always consistent, the broken part is what different threads think is located in the memory.

Comment: I don't see anything in `ImmutableList` or `java.util.concurrent` that will be able to guarantee that the element will be in the list when the caller receives it, only that they will not throw exception.

Answer (score 8):

The `list` being passed into your function is a reference to a list object. If any other threads have references to the same list object, then this is not thread safe.

Comment: I thought all references to parameters are passed by value in Java??? Doesn't this apply here?

Comment: You are passing the reference by value, but it is still a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

```
> Integer getElement( List<Integer> list ) {
> 
>    int i = Random.getInt( list.size() );
> 
>    return list.get( i );
> 
> }
```

> The question: while this <strike>function</strike> method has been called from a thread, IS
>   there a way the list passed to this function can be modified by
>   another thread?

(first Java doesn't have "functions", it has "methods")

It **DEPENDS** on the *List* implementation.  *Integer* is immutable and if you're *List* implementation is immutable and correctly implemented, then the list cannot be modified and is completely threadsafe.

If you're *List* implementation is not immutable, then, yes, the list can be modified by another thread.

An example of an immutable *List* implementation would be, in the excellent Google Guava API, the *ImmutableList* which extends Java *List* and which is fully threadsafe.  There are other examples of fully immutable *List* implementation and they are fully threadsafe (and of course are typically meant to be used with completely threadsafe objects, like the fully immutable *Integer* class).

Comment: It could also be pointed out that it's 2011 and that by now the benefits of immutable data structures seems to be well understood by many people for they simplify both concurrency and reasoning about program behavior.  And you do not necessarily need to be working with "functional" languages like Haskell or Clojure to benefits from the amazing simplicity and power that immutable data structures provide: all you need to do is use good APIs mimicking the power of functional languages.  The impressive **Functional Java** API certainly does come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a list passed to a function thread safe in Java?

A list 'passed to a function' is the same as any other list. It is threadsafe if the list is already threadsafe, or if no other thread can see the list.

Comment: Define threadsafe. For OP it is not threadsafe if it can be modified while `getElement` is accessing it. Which kind of threadsafe List guarantee that behavior?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya there is only one kind of threadsafe. I cannot make any sense of this comment or your question.

Comment: EJP the downvote is not from me but considering you can get it wrong with 15K score I think you should take back your downvote on @TJR (if indeed it was you who downvoted)

Comment: No, there are multiple types of threadsafe. Compare for example `Vector` and `ArrayList`. 

But that is not what OP means here. He is asking if it can be threadsafe such that no other thread can modify it while getElement is accessing it.

You wrote the list is threadsafe if it is already threadsafe. By "already" I assume you mean at the call site. So you mean that there is some data structure that will prevent modification of the list while getElement is accessing it. 

Which data structure is that?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya thanks for finally clarifying, but whenever I see a remark starting 'so you mean' the answer is invariably 'no', as in this case. From that point on, your comment is just fallacious inference. If the list is threadsafe, somehow, it remains threadsafe when passed to a function, and it doesn't magically acquire thread-safety when passed to a function. Passing it to a function doesn't itself affect thread safety in any way. That's what my answer says. And I am still under no obligation to define thread safety. This entire exchange remains pointless as far as I can see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3748/discussion-between-hemal-pandya-and-ejp)

Comment: You may not believe but I really was interested in knowing if there was a way to guarantee that it will not throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't think there is.

Comment: Could please everyone stop upvoting the silly comments from Hemal Pandya?  A Google Guava *ImmutableList* of *Integer* (which is also immutable) is **FULLY IMMUTABLE AND THREADSAFE** and this is a **FACT**.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya No, there are not 'multiple types of threadsafe', and neither of those classes is thread-safe. And if your 'believe it or not' comment is a question, *post it as a question,* not at the end of a futile discussion in comments on someone else's answer to a third party's question. That way somobody might understand what you're actually talking about.

Answer (score -1):

> Is a list passed to a function thread safe in Java?
>
> **The question:** while this function has been called from a thread, **IS** there a way the list passed to this function can be modified by another thread?

This is about thread-safety and specifically about the list instance. It depends on the concrete class of the list instance is (it's concurrent and mutability behaviors). If that instance is mutable, it matters on the visibility/exposure of that list.

I've modified your example in hopes of better understanding the question and provide more concrete solutions:

```java
private void method1 {
  final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
  // Add the hypothetical mutator from another Thread
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      list.clear(); // if this where to happen between first & second access in getElement an IndexOutOfBoundsException would occur
    }
  }).start();
  Integer someInt = getElement(list);
}

// this is not thread-safe
private Integer getElement(List<Integer> list) {
  int len = list.size(); // first access to list
  int idx = Random.getInt(len);
  Integer retval = list.get(idx); // second access to list
  return retval;
}
```

---

Two ways:

1. *concurrent* instances
2. *immutable*

`concurrent` list instances:

- java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
- java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()

Given the above code, here are some options on how to make getElement thread-safe.

## `immutable`

**Best**: make list `immutable` (so that synchronization not necessary)

```java
final List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1);

// or Guava's ImmutableList
final List<Integer> list2 = ImmutableList.of(1);

// the reference to the underlying mutable list is now hidden
final List<Integer> list3 = getList();    
private List<Integer> getList() {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(1); // mutate the list
  return Collection.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Con: causes a new problem to solve with the mutator. Understanding the whole problem would be needed to resolve that.

## `concurrent`

1) Defensive copy in getElement() in combination with `concurrent` instance.

```java
private Integer getElement(Collection<Integer> list) {
   final List<Integer> copy;
   synchronized (list) { // needed if Collections.synchronized*()
     copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
   }
   return copy.get(Random.getInt(list.size()));
}
```

Con: performance to copy

2) Rewrite getElement() so that it only uses an iterator with a `concurrent` instance

```java
// This is just top-of-the-head, 
private <T> T getElement(Iterable<T> list) {
   synchronized(list) { // needed if Collections.synchronized*()
     for(T elem : list) {
       // not even distribution of results, look for better algorithm
       if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
         // this is the one
         return elem;
       }
     }
   }
   return getElement(list); // put in a better fail-safe than this
}
```

Con: current implementation does not provide a uniform distribution

---

There isn't an easy way to solve concurrency.

Comment: TJR [Collections.unmodifiableList(list)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) returns an an **unmodifiable view**. The underlying list can be modified. This only means that the `getElement` method itself cannot modify it. On the other hand @TJR, who seems to have downvoted you also seems to be mistaken that there can be a "threadsafe" list that can guarantee this behavior.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: I didn't downvote anyone (just in case you wonder) but having real immutable lists is **SO** useful that there are a **several** real immutable collections available for Java.  They only give you references to fully constructed lists that **CANNOT** be partially constructed and that **CANNOT** be modified once you get them, hence they **ARE** perfectly thread-safe.  Google's *Guava*'s *ImmutableList* comes to mind (which *extends ImmutableCollection<E> and implements List<E>*).  Trove, *Functional Java*, and a **lot** of other APIs do provide immutable lists too.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r +1 for immutable. Immutable anything is good. And I am not vote police :)

Answer (score -3):

As other have explained there is no way (or it is at least very difficult) for `getElement` to ensure that the `List` cannot be modified while the method is accessing it. If another `Thread` modified is to reduce it size less then random int generated on fist line then the second line will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The only option is to ensure that all threads that have access to the List only do synchronized access. That is:

```
Integer getElement( List<Integer> list ) {
   synchronized(list) {
       int i = Random.getInt( list.size() );
       return list.get( i );
   }
}
// some method that modifies the list
void modify(List<Integer> list ) {
   synchronized(list) {
       ....
   }
}
```

Note that even though `getElement` will succeed there is no guarantee that the element will still exist in the list when the caller uses that element. To ensure that, the callers also need to synchronize:

```
// Thread 1
synchronized (list) {
    Integer someElement = getElement(list);
    use(someElement);
    // use can be outside the synchronized block if it is ok to use 
    // an element that is no longer in the list
}
//Thread 2
synchronized (list) {
    modify(list); // call some function that modifies the list
}
```

A less error-prone approach is to implement a List class that requires it to be locked before it can be accessed. The usage would be as follows:

```
try {
    list.lock();
    Integer someElement = getElement(list);
    use(someElement);
} finally {
    list.unlock();
}
```

This looks somewhat like the previous approach (and will look even more so with [try-with-resources](http://try-with-resources)) the difference is that the List methods get/set etc throw an exception if they are being accessed without acquiring a lock.

EDIT: This of course applies only when using **mutable** lists. The scenario is entirely different when using immutable lists, though you will still need some synchronization mechanism if the element need to be in the list when it is used.

Comment: Looks like the downvote brigade has taken a fondness to this question as well :)

Comment: I have not downvoted, but your answer really looks like a bunch of outdated practices. It is so strange and ineffective to do manual synchronization on collections, when there are a lot of cool concurrent non-blocking implementations around.